# Destroy one session from multiple sessions in php

Tags: php, session, destroy

I have 5 `Session` in my script. I want to `destroy` two from them.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['productid'] = "123";
  $_SESSION['imglink'] = "x.png";
  $_SESSION['oldprize'] = "120";
  $_SESSION['spacialprize'] = "100"
  $_SESSION['productname'] = "AC";
?>
```

Comment: You have 5 **session variables**, not 5 sessions. Note the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[unset()](http://www.php.net/unset)** for this as:

```
unset($_SESSION['productname']);
```

`$_SESSION['productname']` is a variable and `unset()` destroys any variable placed within it.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a Session Value:

```
$_SESSION['productname'] = "AC";
```

If you want to "destroy" this, you can use following function:

```
unset($_SESSION['productname']);
```

If you use "session_unset();" and "session_destroy();" your whole session values are destroyed, and you have to restart a session.

Answer (score 1):

unset($_SESSION['productname']);
unset($_SESSION['productname']);

"session_destroy():" will destroy the whole session

Comment: The same solution answered 2 times, why did you post again?

Comment: The difference between both session_unset and session_destroy is as follows:

session_unset just clears out the session for usage. The session is still on the users computer. Note that by using session_unset, the variable still exists. session_unset just remove all session variables. it does not destroy the session....so the session would still be active.

Using session_unset in tandem with session_destroy however, is a much more effective means of actually clearing out data. session_destroy is destroy the session. session_destroy() to kill all session information

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```php
unset($_SESSION['productname']);
 
unset($_SESSION['productname']);
```

After this, your session will be deleted.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at the other answers, your approach was already mentioned there. In order to keep the site clean and easy to overlook, we try to avoid duplicate answers.